# ARIA implementation for checkbox in datagrid or JQGrid

Tags: checkbox, jqgrid, wai-aria

I have JQGrid whicg has checkbox as column using formatter of JQGrid  . JAWS or screen reader is not reciting the checkbox checked/unchecked event on SPACE BAR / keyboard click. Can anyone help with this.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? You write about both jqGrid and datagrid. Which product you really use? Where is your JavaScript code? You write about the formatter, which you use to create the checkbox. Where is the code of the formatter? Do you set `aria-checked` attribute of the checkbox?

Comment: Is it a proper `<input type="checkbox">`? Do you have a URL or a code sample?